# Release build of iOS MAUI failed with MSB3191 (incorrectly combined path)

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin.ios, maui

Building release of iOS MAUI app (Remote Device) failed with this error message:

**Code** MSB3191
**Description** Unable to create directory "obj/Release/net6.0-ios/ios-arm64//stripped/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dllDevelop\Test\MauiApp1\obj\Release\net6.0-ios\ios-arm64\linked". The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
**File** C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\15.4.446-ci.-release-6-0-4xx.446\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets
**Line** 751

It is a new project created from template ".NET MAUI App" - I just changed Application ID and  Provisioning profile. Windows 10, new installation of Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current, Version 17.3.5. Connected to remote Mac with Xcode 13.3.1.

Debug build of iOS (Local Device or Remote Device) is ok. Release build of other platforms (Android, Windows) is ok...

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

Executing the command `dotnet workload restore "full-path-to-your-sln"` did the magic!

**Update:**
Above command did not work - I had to opt-out ILStripping by editing project file. I added:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)'=='Release|net6.0-ios'">    
  <EnableAssemblyILStripping>False</EnableAssemblyILStripping>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You literally saved my day, thanks bro